# Why is superdeterminism generally regarded as a joke?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, determinism

Before anything, I'm sorry for being an outsider coming to opine about your field. This is almost always a stupid decision, but I do have a good justification for this case. I've been reading about [superdeterminism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdeterminism) and it bothered me that most of you [treat it as a joke](http://motls.blogspot.com.br/2013/10/superdeterminism-ultimate-conspiracy.html). Well, before anything, I think at this point in history we should've already learned the lesson: ridiculous sounding ideas often end up becoming standards science, and that form of idealogical bullying should never exist. But, if at least the arguments were convincing, one could make an excuse for the author. Except not, his arguments sound just like someone with total lack of understanding of idea who rants against it just because he doesn't like it. *"Superdeterminism would mean nature is sending magic agents to control our brains and conspire against us!"* Is this even serious?

Yes, as a computer scientist I do think superdeterminism is the most natural approach to how the universe works. On my view the idea of "free will" - as in, something coming from outside the universe, interacting with the information stored in our brain and determining what we do physically - is the sketchy approach, not the opposite. I do think true randomness is the one that requires a lot of magical intervention, while superdeterminism is much more solid. And I even think [recent insights](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77730/what-is-the-actual-significance-of-the-amplituhedron) support it without need for any "magical agents". But that is not the reason I'm mad - after all, I'm an outsider and my views doesn't matter a dime. It is because such an important idea with huge implications is regarded as a joke and not even considered just for matters of taste, with no actual proof or evidence of the case. And this is something I do have the right to complain, regardless of the field.

So, please, could anyone justify this prejudice?

Comment: Is this better suited for [Philosophy.SE](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I don't know enough about the scope of this SE to opine about that, I'll leave it for you guys to decide.

Comment: Luboš Motl is someone I have enormous respect for (just look at his answers on this forum!) but he has a rather sharp tongue and I suspect many physicists would take a more moderate tone. [Experimental tests of Bell's inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_test_experiments) have convinced most of us that hidden variable theories are unlikely, however that hasn't stopped people looking for loopholes. And good luck to them. It's a relatively small part of the science budget to pay some theorists to have a go at it and I don't begrudge them the opportunity.

Comment: See? "Loopholes". Even you disrespect it, even though you probably didn't notice nor mean to. That is what I'm talking about, it is like it is something so obvious to physicists that you don't even question it. On my view Bell's results relies on the presumption of the existence of "free will", which is a completely shady and unexplained concept. What is that "free will", where it does come from and how does it affect the physical world? How could a conclusion that depends on magical, unexplained concepts have convinced so many physicists ?

Comment: Related: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/9511/3164

Comment: This appears off-topic because it is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Dokkat Physics deals with the natural. As a fundamental branch of science, it is also heavily reliant on trusting observations. In Bell's inequality experiments, we are not so much relying on free will, but rather we are assuming that we have no knowledge of some things (like the setting of a switch). Furthermore, the evidence we have and the observations we make all point to very easily deducible results. As a computer scientist, I am sure that you understand the rigid application of logic. Superdeterminism is not taken very seriously as a physics theory because it is not physics.....

Comment: It requires us to assume and rely on ideas that we cannot possibly test or validate in any way. It describes things which seem to be outside of the natural universe; a domain that falls outside of physics. And, in the end, it does not change anything that we now believe to be true. If super-determinism is correct and there is a will from outside the universe determining our actions, we can never know and to us it will still appear as though there is true randomness; the physics we have based on the ideas of true randomness will continue to work the same as ever; and all of our measurements....

Comment: will continue to tell us that the universe is not deterministic at all. So, in this sense, super-determinism is a joke. It describes something that falls just outside the realm of physics, doesn't change any of the physics we know and love, requires us to have faith that it is correct with no possibility of confirming or falsifying it, and is just edgy enough that it would aggravate most physicists and be believed by some non-physicists. That is why so many are dismissive of it

Comment: Also coming at this from a computer scientist's perspective, I've been thinking along the same lines as Dokkat.

Without getting philosophical, if every particle in the universe consistently obeys physical rules that do not involve true randomness, then the universe must be deterministic. If there exists true randomness, then it must not be. Simple as that. I'm guessing that the existence of true randomness is really what this argument is about, but many of these arguments seem to be put in much vaguer terms.

Comment: "ridiculous sounding ideas often end up becoming standards of science" Not true, you're cherry-picking. You're familiar with the ridiculous ideas that made it; a far, far deal more did fail horribly.

Comment: @Jim this is simply wrong. True randomness is the actual system that **needs** a will from outside the universe determining our actions, while superdeterminism is the only one that can be self-contained.

Comment: @Dokkat: Randomness is basically just a lack of pattern. What makes you say that it requires a "will from outside"? Why would it have that requirement more than any other pattern, or lack of pattern, would?

Comment: Determinism is ruled out by the uncertainty principle. A state where the momentum is known exactly ceases to have any identifiable position. Conversely, a state with a definite position ceases to have any identifiable momentum. It does not say that there is a position that we cannot measure, it says that if you measure the position exactly, then measure the momentum exactly, then measure the position exactly again, then it is equally likely that the particle is found on the other side of the planet as it is in the original position.....

Comment: not having a definite position and momentum (as well as a host of other combinations that don't commute) at the same time means that physical laws simply cannot predict what can happen next. If the universe were superdeterministic then it would be easy to tell the exact position and momentum of a particle. The particle must be found a a certain position in the future because there is no other alternative, if we can predict its position at any time, then we can also know its momentum at any time; something that is impossible.

Comment: however, you might argue that it still works that way, but superdeterminism just happens to make it that however we measure things, we always come up with the result that things look random. In that case, how can we ever actually trust anything scientific? If nature has predetermined that we are to experimentally and theoretically get her wrong, then isn't everything we have now worthless?

Comment: Or, can we not act under the assumption that nature will continue making things look random to us, which would imply that the physics we now believe (that it is not superdeterministic) is good for describing how we expect nature to behave whenever we make measurements. In which case, we can easily ignore superdeterminism even if it is true because it is predetermined that things will appear to us as truly random

Comment: See [Rethinking Superdeterminism](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphy.2020.00139/full).

Comment: See [Superdeterminism: A Guide for the Perplexed](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.01324).

Comment: See [Sabine Hossenfelder & Timothy Palmer - Rethinking Superdeterminism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YglT09Korr0&t=1901s&ab_channel=Newton1665physicsseminars).

Comment: Thanks for the resources! I love this subject.

Answer (score 35):

First of all, "loopholes" is no disrespect. It's standard nomenclature. Given a law, a "loophole" is a way to circumvent it. Bell's inequalities, in their mathematical formulation, are laws that prevent superdeterminism, so if we believe it should exist, we have to find loopholes in the assumptions. It might be that the loophole is so big that the whole law becomes nonsense, but till now, nobody has found one - except the free will.

Except for a few really outspoken critics, I don't think that people regard superdeterminism as a "joke". If you are interested, here is a good summary about what is known by a computer scientist: http://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec18.html
It also tells you that for Bell's inequalities, the concept of "free will" is actually not "murky" but very clear: The detector settings must not be completely predetermined by the history of the universe. You can accept that assumption to be true or not.

In the end, of course, it means you have to decide: Is everything in the universe predetermined, or are there any choices possible that are not fully predetermined by the state of the universe? If the latter exists, you can't have superdeterminism. That's what Bell tells us. So let's assume we have superdeterminism. And then? Nothing. It doesn't give you any new predictions and despite that, it actually tells you that what you are doing is futile anyway, because your experiments don't fulfill the basic requirements we pose about experiments (reproducibility, parameters can be freely set, etc.), so in principle, you could stop right there. Then again, you won't stop, because you're predetermined not to.

Thus superdeterminism is a stance in philosophy not science in its modern form (and this question is not physics, but philosophy) - and many physicists/mathematicians strongly reject philosophy in science, they just don't get anything out of it. So, physicists don't treat superdeterminism as a joke, it's just not a position they feel comfortable with and since it doesn't predict anything anyway, they can just take a different position or none at all.

Comment: Very insightful, thank you! You got many things, so let me start with the "science invalidation" argument. You say that science would be invalidated if our decisions are pre-determined? That doesn't make sense. How so? Not having true free-will doesn't mean we don't percept free will locally. We do think we have it because we don't have enough information to predict our own actions. It works the same as pseudo-random numbers. They may look completely random for a humanbeing, but they are completely pre-determined.

Comment: So, considering science is just a mean for humans to gather information about the universe, it does not matter that, globally, everything is pre-determined. As long as, for us, it looks like we have free will, then, for our own models, science is completely valid.

Comment: Also, you can see the author of that lecture is clever from the first paragraph. Brilliant, ha. Seems like I'll be having a good read now, thanks.

Comment: let's say I'm a scientist and I want to know things about the universe. Let's also say that I want to know what "reality" is. Then, my first assumption should be that I can actually get to know these things. If this assumption is wrong, my conclusions will be faulty. This doesn't "invalidate" science (you misunderstood me there), it just means that I didn't do what I thought I did, because of faulty assumptions - the experiments will of course still show me something about the universe. 
What Bell's theorem tells us is that superdeterminisms must in a way hide from us.

Comment: If superdeterminism is the reality, we may never know. But if we can't find out, it's futile to muse about it outside philosophy. Basically, you just propose a different ontic model (which people don't like, because they like to think they can find out everything), but whose truth cannot be probed. I'd really go to the philosophers with this, they can tell you more about the differences between epistemology and ontology and how this might be important with your question, my knowledge there is pretty shaky!

Comment: Correct, superdeterminism is not generally regarded as a joke. The idea of determinism of any kind is distasteful to many, and I think some physicists and mathematicians recoil from it and simply refuse to consider it, even to the point of coming up with fairly bizarre theories e.g. of consciousness involving quantum gravity to somehow import a "magical" element (looking at you, Penrose). But it isn't a joke.

Comment: If it isn't, at least in principle, testable and refutable... it isn't science. Superdeterminism, like many philosophical/religious questions, simply doesn't occupy the space of questions that science is set up to handle. From this point of view, a difference that makes no difference really is no difference, and if there's no difference between yes and no then the only possible answer is "mu" -- your question is not a question.

Comment: @Martin [Never say never](http://phys.org/news/2012-10-real-physicists-method-universe-simulation.html)

Comment: @keshlam there is no evidence it is not testable nor refutable. Indeed there is no reason to believe so. And finding about it would be a huge scientific feat with big implications.

Comment: If it can't be tested, there is nothing to "find out about" -- just raw belief. If you can come up with some testable prediction which must happen or not happen depending on whether the theory is true or false, then it may or may not eventually become a subject for science. Until you can offer a way to do that, it's the precise equivalent of asking if God can create a stone so large He can't lift it... linguistic games and nothing more than that.

Comment: It is not true that out of superdeterminism comes "nothing." You can start there and build a theory about observations and statistics assuming you are not superdetermined into an "unusual" path but an "average" one. The research program of physics experiments wouldn't change but the meaning of the theory does. There would also be less confusion.

Comment: Superdeterminism is in many cases nonsensical, since you're presuming that all quantum effects understand and are able to predict the future of what _you_, the experimenter, are doing (Since you are deterministic after all). Then, the quantum particles specifically set themselves up to rig the system against Bell's Inequality. As the wikipedia page on superdeterminism mentions, you're presuming that if you seed an RNG with many tiny effects to gain entropy, and you use that high entropy to seed your experiment - _Somehow_, the quantum particles are equally affected by those entropy sources.

Comment: Yes, it does legitimately avoid non-locality, but I find it rather absurd to believe that quantum particles are being affected by the same inputs as your RNG when your RNG is seeding which of the three angles are being tested during your test of Bell's Inequality.

Comment: I mean, let's say you had a physical button to decide which angle to test when your entangled particle arrives. Yes, if you use your fingers to press the button, the quantum particle "Could have known" what you were going to do. But if you had a true, real, RNG, controlling a robot that then pressed the button, the particle is provably forced into superluminal communication to its entangled partner. I think trying to draw a distinction between an RNG robot, and drawing numbers out of a hat, isn't too far from what would be called a "joke".

Comment: Regarding science being invalidated by superdeterminism, consider that superdeterminsim insists that all of our conclusions about the cosmos are predetermined.  Once a conclusion is predetermined, then it is logically superfluous (and not allowed by logic) to also call that conclusion "true" or "rational" because there would be no test that could possibly distinguish between an inevitable conclusion that was true, or rational, and an inevitable conclusion that was not "true" or not rational, or scientifically valid.

Comment: You said, "And then? Nothing. It doesn't give you any new predictions..." but it contradicts to the point made by the author here: http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/16781/1/Det_as_UnifPrincip_011118_6_blck.pdf

Who should I believe?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the paper where the author claims that new prediction have been made. He says "Whether this can be empirically tested is not so clear; but surely, if it turns out to be possible to construct deterministic theories for quantum mechanics, there seem no principled reasons to think there can be no new predictions.". That implies he hasn't got any new predictions. He just believes that new predictions could be made. Well, nothing has turned up so far.

Comment: I'm not trying to say that whatever theory you are developing could not at some point make new predictions. Maybe, maybe not. I'm claiming that all approaches of superdeterminism as they were known in 2014 seemed to preclude new predictions because of their nature. 
The whole field is very complex - there is hardly ever any one person completely right or wrong because it is so very difficult to actually nail down all your model assumptions.

Answer (score 17):

You say "ridiculous sounding ideas often end up becoming standards science" - but take into account that "ridiculous sounding ideas" much more often, by a large factor, end up becoming no science at all.

I agree that "that form of idealogical bullying should never exist" - except that it's not ideological, but just a practical matter of deciding which claims to spend time on understanding and possibly verifying.

When you ask scientists for "actual proof or evidence of the case" - it prove, that some new, and fairly unusual theory is invalid, you ask people to do a lot of work - but why should they do this work?

They would be interested to do this work - without even asking them - if someone provides some kind of evidence convinces them that there is a chance the new idea is at least useful enough to spend time on.
That's all.

I think “**Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence**” (Carl Sagan) applies perfectly to that.

Comment: Note I did not refer to the ideas you cited, and not even to physics for that matter. So it would equally apply to theories like "free energy" or "God".

Comment: OK, I actually agree with most of what you said. But about the problem itself. Do you see how bell's results prove that the world is inherently random **by assuming thoughts are be random**? It proves something by assuming it. I am the only who sees the absurdity on it? Or maybe I'm completely missing something else?

Comment: Oh, looking the question from the perspective of a scientist, I did not, and do not intend to read about the problem itself. Sure, proving something based on the assumption it is true is an error. The first step to sort out this kind of problem when publishing something it the peer review; Was the paper/publication in question peer reviewed?

Answer (score 9):

The real issue here is obscured by inane terminology and bad thinking.

The real issue is, what sort of "locally deterministic theory" could reproduce the experimentally successful predictions of quantum mechanics? Locality here means, not just that causal influences have to pass through space (rather than acting instantly at a distance), but that they don't go faster than light.

The key discovery of John Bell, immortalized in his theorem, is that there are experiments in which quantum mechanics predicts that there are correlations of a sort which cannot be produced by a locally deterministic theory.

The basic paradigm is that two particles are produced at a point, and move apart in opposite directions towards two rotatable filters. There are particle detectors on the far side of both filters. The probability that the particle will get through the filter depends on the filter's angle of orientation. The orientation of the filter is set while the particles are in flight, when they are too far apart for a light-speed influence to connect them. Yet whether they get through the filters or not, is highly correlated in a way that can't be produced by a locally deterministic theory with a light-speed limit. For more, see "Bell's theorem".

Bell's theorem is about probabilities. It is not literally impossible for a locally deterministic physics to reproduce the right results, but it would have to be an endless long-running coincidence, as if cosmic rays kept arriving from the other side of the universe in order to block the particles from getting through with the required frequency.

The point is that the filter orientations can be set according to any rule, the probabilities of getting through at the different ends are both highly correlated with each other *and* depend on what the orientations actually are, and the filter orientations can be "chosen" in such a way that no lightspeed causal influence can connect them. So the hypothetical causal influence that determines whether the particles get through, would have to "know" what the orientations were in advance. And since the orientations could be chosen e.g. according to the digits of pi, or the letters of "Moby Dick", or the behaviors of rats in a maze, you would have to suppose that this sequence of information was programmed into the outside causal influence (like the cosmic rays) in advance.

*That* is the idea that is "regarded as a joke". But here is where the inane terminology and the bad thinking enter to confuse the issue.

Bell posed his scenario in terms of experimenters choosing the filter orientations. He said a loophole might exist, if the experimenters' own choices are not free, and he called this "superdeterminism", as if ordinary determinism was just about experiments and not also the people who make them.

In any case, this offers no improvement in terms of probability. Before, we had cosmic rays with "Moby Dick" pre-programmed into them. Here, we have (presumably) mysterious influences which would prevent experimenters from conducting the "Moby Dick" version of the experiment. It's just as silly, and in any case, Bell-type experiments have now been done many times, so the improbable thing has come to pass. (It would be interesting to have a lower bound on just how improbable the outcomes of all the world's EPR experiments would be by now, assuming local determinism.)

So, although there actually is a prejudice against determinism among many people brought up on quantum mechanics, and although many people have a philosophical prejudice in favor of free will, neither of those really has anything to do with the issue here. The core issue is the fact that locally deterministic theories can only produce Bell correlations by coincidence, and that has a probability approaching zero as the experiments keep getting repeated and the predictions confirmed. If you want determinism in subquantum physics, you need nonlocality (Bohmian mechanics), causality backwards in time (various "interpretations"), perhaps some form of emergent space (with an underlying causal network that is nonlocal)...

[This paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4119) is a more accurate and scholarly expression, using a contemporary form of causal analysis, of what I am trying to say. When I say it needs cosmic rays pre-programmed with Moby Dick... that's an example of what they call "fine-tuning". The local causal influences responsible for producing nonlocal Bell correlations would have to be tuned in advance to produce the required effects.

Comment: Yes, I understand all that you are saying. I think the problem is that there is such a ingrained concept of flow of time in our brains. The orientations could be defined in function of whatever we want, it doesn't make it any absurd. Maybe if, instead of a static time, you think that the decision of modifying it alters something in the past, then it will sound less magical. This way it is not like the universe understands that we are orienting the filters in function of moby dick's characters. It is just that we affect the past after making such a decision.

Answer (score 7):

> Why is superdeterminism generally regarded as a joke?

My personal (somewhat facetious) answer to that would be because people lack imagination. I don't think of superdeterminism in terms of conspiracies, but rather retrocausality, and do not find it ridiculous if phrased this way.

Basically, I don't believe there's really something like a physically significant arrow of time - just an arrow of *perception* of time. Reality doesn't care how we subjectively experience time as somehow flowing from one moment to the next.

Some anecdotal evidence for this: First, relativistic theories are reparametrization-invariant - there isn't really a preferred notion of time. Then, there's the idea due to Stueckelberg and Feynman that anti-particles are basically just particles propagating backwards in time, or the time-symmetric reformulation of electrodynamics. Also, there's the fact that in general relativity, we need to solve for a consistent space-time (which takes future 'boundary conditions' into account), with the aggravation that space-time might possibly have a non-trivial topology at the quantum level.

This is also the basic idea behind the (somewhat naive) transactional interpretation of quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are prejudiced yourself if you say 'I do think superdeterminism is the most natural approach to how the universe works'. This is not meant as criticism, I just want to say that your mind is shaped by the world you perceive, and that world *looks* deterministic.

Quantum mechanics and its randomness represent a different view on the (microscopic) world, and it does look unnatural to a mind that is shaped by the behavior of the (macroscopic) world. When I studied physics, it took me years to get some intuitive understanding of the quantum mechanical world, because it contradicted my intuitive understanding of the world of classical physics in so many ways.

Personally, I am glad about the randomness in quantum mechanics, because to me it seems that it negates determinism and makes free will possible.

Comment: Is it the last sentence that lead to the downvotes? Downvoters please say why you downvote otherwise no-one learns anything. I don't agree with the last sentence either, but aside from that this is a very good answer to the OP's question, so +1

Comment: So why don't you agree with the last sentence?

Comment: People disagree with the last sentence because randomness is not freedom - people who think free will is nonsensical upon close inspection think you either choose because of causes or you choose randomly, and neither of those is intuitive "free will". Randomness actually gives us less power over our choices because at least when they're deterministic our mind can be part of the feedback loop that makes up the causes, but randomness takes no feedback. It only feels intuitively freeing as an "out" if your intuition is that a lack of free will is constraining, but it is merely explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

Ideas shouldn't be treated as jokes but superdeterminism is false: it is incompatible with the best available theory of knowledge.

First, a digression on the theory of knowledge. Any instance of adaptive complexity has to be explained. For example, as Paley noted, if you find a watch and notice that its parts fit together in such a way that they accurately tell time and that a small change in the arrangements of the parts would destroy its ability to tell time, then some process must have set it up to do that. The information required to set up such a system is knowledge. Philosophers often think of knowledge as being something a person believes but adaptive complexity in an artefact like a watch or the wing of a bird or whatever all require explanation and the explanation has to be pretty similar in each case because what requires explanation is pretty similar. Namely, whatever set up the system has to have started out without that information and then created it. Since it didn't start out with the knowledge, it can't just magically produce the right answer in a single leap, rather it has to produce variations on its current information and then selected among those variations. There has to be some medium in which the information is stored and can be easily accessed, read and used to produce things like watches or butterfly wings or whatever. In the case of artefacts that humans make, the information can be stored in books, computer programs and so on. In the case of biological evolution, the information is stored in genes. But any such information has to be stored somewhere.

If superdeterminism was true then there would have to be some system that can mess about with the human brain in such a way as to gives people specific ideas. It would not be enough to make random changes because such changes would not produce the idea of making a specific measurement. A random change might produce an epileptic fit or brain damage or the brain might just ignore it depending on the kind of change but it won't produce a specific idea. So where is this system? Where does it store the information required to manipulate human experimenters? How did it create that knowledge without anybody noticing?

And suppose that such a system existed and that it had somehow concealed itself from us. Why would it do that when it could cooperate for mutual benefit? Even if it has a much greater information storage capacity or processing speed or whatever, surely it can figure comparative advantage or at least read about it in economics books? Comparative advantage means you should do what you're best at and leave other people to do stuff you're not so good at. So if it can do numerical integration in fifty dimensions without breaking a sweat and it had a reason to do so it could contract out less urgent stuff to humans.

Finally, I think the problem physicists have with quantum mechanics is largely that they fail to take it seriously as a description of how the world works. For example, quantum mechanics is a local theory and the non-locality is a result of trying to force it into a classical shape, see

http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007

http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223

Comment: " it is incompatible with the best available theory of knowledge. " **No.** Determinism, technically, is unfalsifiable and cannot be incompatible with any experimental result. (Even apparently random results could be in principle be pre-scripted - the Creator may have pre-scripted every quantum collapse). Unable to downvote as I lack rep.

Comment: There are two problems with your comment. First, I didn't say determinism is false, I said superdeterminism is false. Determinism and superdeterminism are not the same. Superdeterminism claims that somehow an experimental apparatus is correlated with the tests we are going to do. Second, the theory of knowledge is not experimentally testable (see "Logic of Scientific Discovery" by Karl Popper, Chapter 2) so an idea could be incompatible with it and also not be experimentally testable.

Comment: Firstly superdeterminism is determinism of the whole universe including the experimenter. That's the normal use of the word determinism, the super is superfluous. If you want to *exclude* the experimenter the word is dualism. Secondly your argument why determinism conflicts with the theory of knowledge makes no sense. Nobody says determinism has to be random.

Comment: Superdeterminism is a stronger position than determinism of the whole universe. Superdeterminism specifically states that the experimental apparatus will be correlated in a specific way with the experiment you decide to do: this is required to explain the results of EPR experiments. I didn't say determinism or superdeterminism has to be random: I don't know where you got that idea.